# Snapping polygon layer to another layer automatically

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, snapping, digitizing

I have two polygon layers in QGIS 3.4: 'Layer A' and 'Layer B'. These two layers have been digitized separately. Some features in these two layers are crossing or not meeting each other in some areas which I have to fix this problem.

'Layer A' is an accurate layer in terms of boundary so I want all the features in 'Layer B'  be snapped to the closest feature (point) in 'Layer A'.

Currently I try to move and snap all the vertexes in 'Layer B' to 'Layer A' manually using digitizing tool in QGIS which is very time consuming and I might miss some of them

So my question is: How can I do this process automatically or at least semi automatic?

Comment: Does this help https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_snapper.html ?

Comment: @MichaelStimson This is for QGIS 2.14 and I can't find it in QGIS3.4 do you know anything similar for QGIS 3.4?

Comment: How about "Snap geometries to layer" in the "Vector geometry" algorithms section of Processing Toolbox?

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two possible solutions:

**1. Use Geoprocessing / [Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference)**

A simple approach is to create a buffer around layer B - set the buffer distance high enough that all white spaces between the two layers are covered. See screenshot: Layer A: orange; Layer B: blue; buffered Layer B: red outline.

[image]

Now use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Difference` and set the buffer layer as `input` and Layer A as `Overlay layer`. You get a perfectly fitting version of layer B, with layer A unchanged:

[image]

---

**Snap vertices of layer B to nearest vertex of layer A**

For QGIS 3.16 or higher, there is another option. You can use basically the same procedure as [described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384516/88814):

The idea is to create two points layer, representing the vertices of the two polygon layers using Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices). Than "snap" the points of layer B to the closest point of layer A using the new `overlay_nearest` expression, see [visual changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core). Create a new point layer with Menu Processing / Toolbox / [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) and this expression, based on input layer B:

```
array_first (
    overlay_nearest( 
        'layer_A', 
        $geometry
    )
)
```

Than connect the points using Menu Processing / Toolbox / [Points to path`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) and from these path create a polygon with Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / [Lines to polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#lines-to-polygons).