# Using advanced digitizing tools over multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I need to make movements in different layer polygons at the same time (I mainly use move feature and rotate feature tools). I've seen some posts explaining how to do this in multiple steps, but the solutions normally require to join layers or adding fields to the features table, which i can't do, since I'm working in a database and I'm not allowed to do such things. However, the posts I've seen are quite old. It's still not possible to do this using the regular tools for those purposes? Is there any other way to do that?

I'm using QGIS 3.28.9 and I've already tried

- Move feature and rotate feature tools (apparently not possible to modify more than one layer at the same time)
- This same tools, but using batch processing (I need to modify the layers directly from the database,and for this option it's necessary to export the output into a new layer)
- Using the Multiple Layer Selection Plugin to try to select all the features and see if I can move them together this way (apparently the plugin is not working right now). Also, probably it's the same as selecting the different layer features manually, and I've already tried that.

Comment: See [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427018/qgis-use-move-feature-for-two-layers-with-different-geometry-at-once-with-attr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427018/qgis-use-move-feature-for-two-layers-with-different-geometry-at-once-with-attr). The Vertex tool method should still work, although it can be quite resource-intensive.