# How to snap to items bounded within another layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, snapping

How would I go about snapping polygons added within one shapefile layer to a larger bounding polygon in a different shapefile layer? For example if I have a layer with the bounding coastlines of a continent mapped out, how would I go about adding a political map layer that the edges of the political map snap to the edges of the coast?

It seems almost like the inverse of the "Avoid Overlap" Snap setting.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data?

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384574/88814

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This you can achieve with the tracing tool, which is part of the snapping toolbar:

[image]